# Where I can see realistic indexes of reflection for metal\specular reflections\roughness, etc?

Tags: photorealism, pbr

For different materials like wood, paper, skin, etc?

Comment: https://corona-renderer.com/forum/index.php?topic=2359.0

Comment: Thanks! Those units needs conversion formula (like Fresnel) to blender or work as it is?